# Can't connect to internet with wired connection

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, ethernet, wired

I'm unable to get my ethernet socket working to allow me to connect to the internet. Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. WIFI connection to the same modem is functioning. The Ethernet light turns green on the modem when I plug the cable into my computer's ethernet port, so the issue seems to be software, not hardware.

---

The command `sudo pppoeconf`

Returns the following error

*Sorry, I scanned 2 interfaces, but the Access Concentrator of your provider did not respond. Please check your network and modem cables. Another reason for the scan failure may also be another running pppoe process which controls the modem.*

I've checked and pppoe is installed

```
Package: pppoeconf
Status: install ok installed
```

---

I typed sudo poff dsl-provider & it said

```
/usr/bin/poff: No pppd is running.  None stopped.
```

---

---

```
ip a
results in
enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000     link/ether 2c:d4:44:92:0a:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff     inet 193.987.1.235/24 scope global enp2s0        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever     inet6 fe80::2ed4:44ff:fe92:a7d/64 scope link         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I typed `sudo lshw -C network; sudo iwlist scanning; cat /etc/network/interfaces; cat /etc/lsb-release; lspci -nn; lsusb; uname -a; dmesg | grep ound; dmesg | grep b43; iwconfig; sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

& it returned

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 2230
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: c4
       serial: 84:a6:c8:1e:fb:2c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-56-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:30 memory:f1500000-f1501fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 07
       serial: 2c:d4:44:92:0a:7d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0404000-f0404fff memory:f0400000-f0403fff
enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp1s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 40:9B:CD:97:A9:DC
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Internet"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000011f539a15
                    Extra: Last beacon: 128ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0008496E7465726E6574
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A9C0117FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000100000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000100000000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706474220010D10
                    IE: Unknown: DDAD0050F204104A00011010440001021057000101103B00010310470010BC329E001DD811B28601409BCD97A9DC1021001852616C696E6B20546563686E6F6C6F67792C20436F72702E1023001C52616C696E6B20576972656C6573732041636365737320506F696E74102400065254323836301042000831323334353637381054000800060050F20400011011000A44534C2D33373832545410080002218C103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000
          Cell 02 - Address: D8:47:32:86:5B:F4
                    Channel:3
                    Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TP-Link_5BF4"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000179ff13e18d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2424ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000C54502D4C696E6B5F35424634
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030103
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 33082001020304050607
                    IE: Unknown: 33082105060708090A0B
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010010
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD310050F204104A00011010440001021047001038833092309218839C77D84732865BC4103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEC1117FFFF000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1603000700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080100000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000
          Cell 03 - Address: 8C:59:73:A0:6E:A0
                    Channel:10
                    Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
                    Quality=33/70  Signal level=-77 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"italk-6EA0"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001b7fef41dda
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1436ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000A6974616C6B2D36454130
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010A
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEC1117FFFF000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160A000600000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000100000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000100000000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706474220010D10
                    IE: Unknown: DDB90050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010BC329E001DD811B286018C5973A06EA01021001A5A7978656C20436F6D6D756E69636174696F6E7320436F72702E1023001E5A7958454C20496E7465726E65742053686172696E6720476174657761791024000C414D47313330322D543131431042000D533138324532393030373730391054000800060050F20400011011000C414D47313330322D5431314310080002200C103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000
          Cell 04 - Address: 80:20:DA:7C:EC:AE
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TALKTALK7CECB1"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000002359b086ea2
                    Extra: Last beacon: 992ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000E54414C4B54414C4B374345434231
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 0706474220010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 200100
                    IE: Unknown: 23020F00
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 0B0502000D0000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD0117FFFFFF0000000000000080017800000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080400000000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD9F0050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010AA6C51D2F0061E7B5A48ABB31922723210210008536167656D636F6D10230010536167656D636F6D464153543533363410240007332E302D332E301042000F4E373139303938344E3030343138311054000800060050F204000110110015536167656D636F6D46415354353336342D4E373139100800022000103C0001031049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180202101C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 05 - Address: 10:06:45:56:6C:84
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"PLUSNET-CTJQN7"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000002359d46edd4
                    Extra: Last beacon: 976ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000E504C55534E45542D43544A514E37
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 0706474220010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AFC181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD800050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700102E08E1B91EBF83CD8806250C14B473531021000842726F6164636F6D1023000842726F6164636F6D1024000631323334353610420004313233341054000800060050F20400011011000A42726F6164636F6D415010080002200C103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180206F02C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1e14] (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1e16] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM75 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e5d] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0887] (rev c4)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. Name: ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b302 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Linux Navaged 5.4.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 23 19:20:19 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[    0.014494] No NUMA configuration found
[    0.127263] core: PMU erratum BJ122, BV98, HSD29 worked around, HT is on
[    0.192367] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 7 devices
[    0.418914] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    0.419185] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.438902] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    0.439139] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.477994] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[    0.478006] ima: No architecture policies found
[    0.512811] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.
[    0.525735] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.
[    0.690389] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[    0.915546] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    0.915887] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.931549] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    0.931858] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.327598] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0138, bcdDevice=38.82
[    1.333315] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0745, bcdDevice= 6.34
[    1.569495] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    1.613574] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b302, bcdDevice=17.14
[    1.764073] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07da, bcdDevice=78.69
[    4.407993] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    6.732106] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device FJ Camera (04f2:b302)
[    6.901593] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    6.901596] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[    6.901597] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    7.102570] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    7.157161] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input15
[    7.157256] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input16
[    7.157354] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input17
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Internet"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 40:9B:CD:97:A9:DC   
          Bit Rate=39 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1245   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.service.

networking
drivers
network-manager
```

Comment: how you checked if the lan-connection it set on dynamic IP or are you using a static ip? do you use a mac-filter on your router? and please post the output of `ip a` with the lan cable connected. I have none of your packages installed and it work fine for me. That a wire connection is not scalable make sense, because it is not frequency dependent like wlan.

Comment: Thanks! Output of `ip a` https://pastebin.com/TJsGKWJF
When I changed the Wan setting to dynamic the modem stopped having an internet connection for the WIFI too and had to set it back to pppoe. It was originally set to pppoa but neither seems to work. https://cdn.imgchest.com/files/g4z9cek5872.png @Deepwater

Comment: You modem have two sides. One is `wan` witch use `pppoe`. Don't change this. On you lan side on moded you have, usually, 4 `lan` port's. When you put cable from `lan` port from your router in `lan` port of your `pc` did you get green light on modem port indicator? Also you don't need `pppoe` packets on your `pc`.

Comment: Yes the green light turns on the modem port indicator. @2707974

Comment: If your `modem` give ip to your `pc`, you will see with command `ip a` on interface `enp2s0`. With command `ip route` you will see you `gateway`. Something like `default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp2s0` .... If you have this, try `ping 1.1.1.1`. If you get response then try `ping google.com`. If you do not get response on second command, problem is `DNS`. Sheck with command ` cat /etc/resolv.conf` do you have some `nameserver xx.xx.xx.xx` ....

Comment: Thanks. I included the ip a read outs in my original message. Ping isn't working. Thanks for that suggestion. I'm not using any name servers. It's a home laptop connected directly to the ISP modem  @2707974

Comment: Your `ip a` command shows that your `enp2s0` interface does not have an IP address, so obviously it cannot connect. Is it configured to use DHCP? And is your router configured to provide IP addresses both for wired and wireless network (and not for wireless only)? Also, did you shutdown your wireless interface before trying to connect via the wired one?

Comment: Thanks! 1) DHCP is enabled when I log into the modem via browser. Searched for ubuntu DHCP & only ubuntu server information came up 2) I have WAN & WIFI settings in the modem so I think it can provide to both. [Here](https://cdn.imgchest.com/files/j7mmco3e976.png) & [Here](https://cdn.imgchest.com) 3) Yes, I turned off WIFI when attempting to connect. When I enter the settings from the settings area I have no options except to set up a VPN @raj

Comment: As for 1), I asked if DHCP is enabled for interface `enp2s0` in Network Manager in your Ubuntu system. Open your wired connection in Network Manager and check IPv4 settings.

Comment: Thanks for your patience Raj & sorry for not following your advice properly. When I enter network manager I have no options to do anything. [Here is a screenshot to show the only options I have](https://cdn.imgchest.com/files/w7w6cbzxeye.png) @raj

Comment: It's really strange why your wired connection isn't there. Do you have a network icon in the top panel? (I'm asking because I use a different desktop from the default GNOME shell). After clicking it, a menu should pull down and there should be an option "Modify connections". It allows to do more than the Settings app. You can try to add "Ethernet" type connection there.

Comment: [This is what I see](https://cdn.imgchest.com/files/wye3cr85o4b.png) & when I click Wired Settings it sends me to the Network Manager screen I showed in the previous message. @raj

Comment: It says "Unmanaged", so Network Manager doesn't activate it - something must be wrong with the configuration. What happens if you click "Connect" below it? You can try to add the interface manually in Network Manager by running `nm-connection-editor` command, maybe then it becomes managed. I made a short video for you: http://rafa.eu.org/share/network/net-1.ogv

Comment: ` nm-connection-editor` allowed me to manually add an ethernet connection! I'll play around with it and see. Earlier I was also able to get `ip a` to sjhow that the ethernet had an ip address so fingers crossed. @raj

Comment: I added my mac address, ip address and gateway that I found through terminal commands. The netmask I left at 24. Still can't connect and it still says 'wired unmanaged' from the drop down menu. Network manager still has nothing.

Answer (score 0):

from the `ip a` output, you can see that the Wlan connection `wlp1s0` is connected by IPv4 and not via IPv6. For your `enp2s0` you just have enable IPv6. My assumption your router just use IPv4 for your local network, so you have to enable the IPv4 protocol on you ethnernet connection.
It should be visible in the taskbar, where you also can change the configuration.

---

Edit

Okay I guess it is the same issue link [in this post](https://www.ethicalhackx.com/fix-wired-network-interface-device-managed-error-debian-kali-linux/). Therefor try to check if the setting okay with `sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`and chang the line with `managed=false` to `managed=true`. After that restart the networkmanager `sudo service network-manager restart`.

Just for comparison, you should see something [like this](https://images.app.goo.gl/QHqn1yJvhQJQcYYy5) in the network tab. Since I use a different Ubuntu distribution I can not test it directly.

---

Edit:2

I found maybe to possible solution depending what really is missing in your case. Since `ip -a` show your wired interface I assume that your driver is working.
So hopefully you just need create the connection: Try this
`sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`and add with a empty line

```
auto eth0
iface etho inet dhcp
```

so it should look like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface etho inet dhcp
```

With the information proved, this should help.

Comment: In network manager I have no options to do anything except `VPN` and `network proxy`. [Here are the only options I see upon entering Network Settings](https://cdn.imgchest.com/files/w7w6cbzxeye.png)  @waterofdark

Comment: 1) I changed the config file  but the Network Manager screen remains the same. 2) I was able to change `IPv6` to `IPv4` using terminal commands. `ip a` then showed that the ethernet port had an ip address, but still couldn't connect. 3) I restarted just to check the network manager and the ethernet port has disabled. I enabled it in terminal but now it's not displaying an ip address @waterofdark

Comment: 4) `sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.235/24 dev enp2s0` and then `ip a` shows: `enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:d4:44:92:0a:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 193.987.1.235/24 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2ed4:44ff:fe92:a7d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`
@waterofdark

Comment: you can add this information on your question, so everybody can find all the information in one place.

Comment: `[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no` is what networkmanager.config looks like. When I added the suggested code netowrk manager disappeared. @waterofdark

Comment: Now when I run `sudo pppoeconf` there's this error in the terminal.

`awk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\:' is not a known regexp operator
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
`
should I investigate this further maybe? @waterofdark

Comment: why are you using `ppoeconf` in the first place? I guess the router should handle all the stuff so why not removing it?

Comment: Well before I came here to seek advice I searched for how to set up an ethernet connection and a few places talked about this pppoe and that the config would automatically set it up. Ok I'll uninstall.
I Was able to access network settings through `nm-connection-editor.` I manually tried to set up a connection from instructions on google but it had no luck. Sorry for all this @waterofdark

Comment: the pppoeconf is for setting a ADSL connecting, which normale is done by your router so you do not need it to connect to your router. Does it work now, that is not clear from your comment?

Comment: Still nothing. I deleted pppoe. Through `nm-connection-editor` I was able to manually add an ethernet connection. I added the mac address. IP address and router gateway. The netmask came up as 24 and I left it at that. I still have no options within network manager and from the panel it still says 'Network Unmanaged.' Clicking connect does nothing.@waterofdark

Comment: I do not understand what you did. I found a mistake in my Answer and correct it. I know that you need to create wireconnection profile and set it to automatic (DHCP). Or the configuration of your router is need as well. If you add this information, pls edit your question to add this kind of details.
But at the moment I think I can not help you with this.

Comment: I created a wired connection profile but automatic DHCP did nothing. I checked my router and it allowed for automatic DHCP. I then manually added the connection settings and still nothing. @waterofdark

Comment: So you are able to see the wired connection in your network setting? [link]https://images.app.goo.gl/QHqn1yJvhQJQcYYy5 Something like this

Comment: [These are still the only things I can see](https://cdn.imgchest.com/files/w7w6cbzxeye.png). When I changed the `network.conf` file  to `managed=true` as suggested it still had noe ffect on network manager. @waterofdark

Comment: [This is what I see when I use](https://cdn.imgchest.com/files/pyq9cdl8842.png) `nm-connection-editor.`  and when I add a connection [I see this screen here](https://cdn.imgchest.com/files/myd5cqaoj4b.png) @waterofdark

Comment: If you see [this screen](https://cdn.imgchest.com/files/myd5cqaoj4b.png) edit the `IPv4 setting`, the other parts look good.

Comment: I set the ip4 settings for it a few days ago, but still nothing. Added the ip address, netmask amd gateway. I left the DNS servers blank as it referred to a domain. @waterofdark

Comment: If you add the IP adresses it is not DHCP and will most likely not work.